# Lots of objects with OnMouseDown VS Raycasting: Is one better than the other?

Tags: unity, raycasting

I have a grid of gameobjects with colliders. Currently they all have unity's inbuilt **void OnMouseDown** function which gets called when the mouse clicks on a collider. This then executes some game logic on the gameobject.

I realise that I could instead use a seperate script to send a raycast when the player clicks and if it intersects with one of the afformentioned gameobjects I can execute the code that way.

Is one approach better than the other? Or behind the scenes is unity using the raycast method for **void OnMouseDown** anyway? (Or is there perhaps a non-performance reason why you'd use one approach rather than the other)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Behind `OnMouseDown`, Unity is transforming your mouse position from window coordinates to view coordinates, projecting into the world using the view-projection transform and testing this ray against `Collider`s that have the right "layer mask" for `OnMouseDown` receivers.

You should be able to see what it actually calls to do this in the profiler. It's probably just exactly would want to do if you are using `Collider`s or Unity's physics module more generally. IIRC it uses `RayCast`.

A motivation for doing it yourself would be that you can specify a layer mask when calling `RayCast`, so that fewer `Collider`s are tested, which could benefit performance.

Another motivation could be that you want to take control of when exactly the ray tests happen, rather than supply a callback to an opaque system, whether for performance or just preference.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for. That last part about layermasks is spot on for me, although I don't think I need a layermask now it's entirely possible I could later on in development.

Comment: Yes, I wouldn't bother about it unless you find a need to for some reason. If the profiler says your spending a lot of time checking rays from mouse clicks, I'd sanity check the collision layers before writing any code.

Comment: I added another possibly reason to DIY to my answer.